# Extract Data for 2 years and convert number to month

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have the following table with the month and year separated that I would like to join to create a date (as I do not have day this can be set to the first)

```
Measurement mm  yyyy
15000   1   2014
16000   2   2014
15000   5   2013
16000   3   2014
15000   4   2014
16000   5   2014
15000   6   2013
16000   7   2012
```

so I would like the output as:

```
15000 01/01/2014
16000 01/02/2014
```

etc.

only for the last 2 years.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Measurement,DT FROM
(
    SELECT Measurement,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY YYYY DESC) RNK,
    CONVERT(varchar(11),'01'+'/'+CAST(MM AS VARCHAR(2))+'/'+CAST(YYYY AS VARCHAR(4)),103) DT
    FROM #TEMP
)TAB
WHERE RNK IN(1,2)
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58b58/1)

**UPDATE**

I am updating as per your new requirement

Here we will get all month and `LEFT JOIN` with you table

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT 1 ID, CAST('01/01/2013' AS DATE) DT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID+1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DT) FROM CTE1
    WHERE ID<12
)
SELECT ID,DATENAME(MONTH,DT) [MONTH],TP.*,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY YYYY DESC) RNK
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE1
LEFT JOIN TEMP TP ON CAST(TP.MM AS NUMERIC(3,0)) = CAST(CTE1.ID AS NUMERIC(3,0))
```

Now we declare 2 variables, first variable to get values to show rows of month as columns and the second one to replace `NULL with zero`

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @NullToZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [MONTH] + ']', 
              '[' + [MONTH] + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ID,[MONTH] FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY ID

SET @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+[MONTH]+'],0) AS ['+[MONTH]+']' 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT [MONTH],ID FROM #NEWTABLE GROUP BY [MONTH],ID)TAB  
ORDER BY ID  FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Now we select the last two years in your table and pivot it

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT yyyy,' + @NullToZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT yyyy, [MONTH], Measurement FROM #NEWTABLE
                 WHERE RNK IN(1,2)
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(Measurement)
                 FOR [MONTH] IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) p
              WHERE yyyy IS NOT NULL
              ORDER BY yyyy;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c5d21/4)

Comment: Can I ask whether this is a valid date after it has been converted?

Comment: Yes. For safety you can cast as CAST(DT AS DATE) @user1824963

Comment: Many thanks but it seems Visual Studio does not recognise that as a date? Sorry not sure what you mean by CAST (DT AS Date)

Comment: Is it working from the part of SQL Server? @user1824963

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at this wrong I am trying to get 2 series returned to populate a chart by month, I thought this would do the trick but it looks like this is just one series?

Comment: I didn't get you @user1824963

Comment: Many apologies, I am creating a side by side chart for this year and last year

Comment: If you have received the result what you have asked for in the question, you can mark as right answer because the next time some one search for the same solution he/she can easily identify it @user1824963

Comment: Thanks Sarath, let me create an example in Excel and get back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67212/discussion-between-sarath-avanavu-and-user1824963).

Comment: Did you the expected result? @user1824963